# Binding IsVisible in Xaml Maui not working

Tags: maui, maui-windows

I am trying to make a picker be visible on condition from viewmodel and binding in xaml instead of hard code on the code behind. But it is not working.

The code for xaml is:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Power_Aid_Solution.Expenses"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Power_Aid_Solution"
            x:DataType="vm:ExpenseViewModel"
             BindingContext="{vm:ExpenseViewModel}"
             Title="Expenses">
    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="500">
        <Picker Title="Select Origin" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Location}"/>
        <Picker Title="{Binding Path=IsVisible}" IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsVisible}" x:Name="pickerTest"/>

        <Label x:Name="testLabel" Text="{Binding Path=IsVisible}"/>        
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

the viewmodel:

```
namespace Power_Aid_Solution
{
    public class ExpenseViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ExpenseViewModel() 
        {
            _expenses = new();
            _location = new()
            {
                "Office", "Project"
            };
            
        }

        private bool isVisible=true;
        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get => isVisible;
            set 
            {
                if (isVisible == value) return;
                isVisible = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsVisible))); 
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<string> _location;
        public ObservableCollection<string> Location
        {
            get { return _location; }
            set
            {
                _location = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Location)));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Other binding properties are working, only isvisible is not working.

Comment: Can I recommend using CommunityToolkit.MVVM. It saves you from writing all this boilerplate code for the binding. One annotation [ObservableProperty] above your isVisibel, and you are done. Prevents mistakes, speeds up coding.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code,I created a demo , and it works on my side.
And I added a button to change the  value of `IsVisible`, the UI could update automatically.

You can refer to the following code:

**NewPage1.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp119.NewPage1"
             Title="NewPage1">
    
    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="500">
        <Picker Title="Select Origin" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Location}"/>
        <Picker Title="the second picker" IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsVisible}" x:Name="pickerTest"/>

        <Label x:Name="testLabel"  Text="testLabel"  IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsVisible}"/>

        <Button  Text="text"  Command="{Binding TestCommand }"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**NewPage1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class NewPage1 : ContentPage 
{
      public NewPage1()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BindingContext = new ExpenseViewModel();
      }
}
```

**ExpenseViewModel.cs**

```
public class ExpenseViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public ExpenseViewModel()
    {
    }

    public ICommand TestCommand => new Command(TestMethhod);

    private void TestMethhod(object obj)
    {
        IsVisible= false; 
    }

    private bool isVisible = true;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get => isVisible;
        set
        {
            if (isVisible == value) return;
            isVisible = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsVisible)));
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

I don't understand why you set the `Title` for `Picker` and `Text` for Label using `Binding`.

I replaced above code with:

```
      <Picker Title="the second picker" IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsVisible}" x:Name="pickerTest"/>

      <Label x:Name="testLabel"  Text="testLabel"  IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsVisible}"/>
```

Comment: That was for path debugging. Must have done it wrong. Command method is working fine so far. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. What exactly do you want to achieve?Can you elaborate?